# GWTP: onUnbind() never called after closing a presenter

Tags: java, gwt, binding, event-handling, gwtp

I have a GWTP MyPresenter that registers a handler at onBind(), and it works perfectly. The problem is when I leave the presenter using the BACK arrow on the browser. The onUnbind() is never called (I tried with an breakpoint overriding the method, but is never executed). So that this handler is never unregistered. What is wrong? Thanks.

```
public class MyPresenter extends
    PresenterWidget<ViewDiagramPresenter.MyView> {
    [...]

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        registerHandler(getEventBus().addHandler(myEvent.getType(), myHandler));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall `onUnBind()` is not called when the `Presenter` is hidden, that would trigger the `onHide()` method. Specifically, I think the `onUnBind()` should be called manually - you could eg. chain it if you override `onHide()`.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,