# GWTP: clear presenters on logout

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Im using GWTP in my GWT app and have the following architecture:

```
LoginPresenter (Presenter)
    DashboardPresenter (TabContainerPresenter)
        TabbedPresenter1 (Presenter)
        TabbedPresenter2 (Presenter)
        TabbedPresenter3 (Presenter)
```

The first time I start my app, the onBind and addTab methods are called in the DashboardPresenter and when I navigate to a tab, the onbind method is called on that presenter.

If I create a PlaceRequest and navigate back to LoginPresenter via my PlaceManager (by pressing a logout button), I return to the login presenter.

The problem is that if I login again, then all the onBind methods are not called because they are still in memory. onReset and onReveal are called correctly, but I would very much like that each Presenter are reset and that the onBind will be called on each login.

I decide on the login event which tabs should be visible for user and restrict tabs in the addTab method of the DashboardPresenter if the user does not have sufficient rights to see those tabs. But as of now, the tabs are setup the first time a user logs in, but not the next time. This means that if a user with lesser rights logs in after an admin user, he can see the same tabs as the admin. Not good!

How should I deal with this? I would very much like to "reset" all presenters or the session when a user logsout (navigating to the login page). Is it the Ginjector that needs to be "reset", so that it does not return the same binded objects as before?

Just to clarify: we do have server side security which prohibits users with no rights to access sensitive data. But when the user logs in, the gwt app receives a list of features which the user can access. This is used for customizing the UI to fit the rights of the user. (E.g. customize the visible tabs based on users privileges).

Comment: I should add that Im not currently using the unbind methods on the presenters, since im not sure what happens exactly when these methods are invoked.

Comment: My solution, at the moment, is to do a complete page reload using Window.Location.reload(). Im not very fond of this, but it does the trick. Still need a good solution on "resetting" my web app on a logout event...

Comment: FYI the `onUnBind()` methods should be called manually, thus they're not applicable in your situation (Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396992/gwtp-onunbind-never-called-after-closing-a-presenter/13397858#13397858).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this work:

But you could try to fire a `LogoutEvent` on the global `EventBus` , handle it in all `Presenters` that need to be "unloaded" (`TabbedPresenter1`, etc) and call `onUnbind()` on them. 
Afterwards navigate back to the `LoginPresenter`

Alternatively you could make us of a custom `TabData` (subclass `TabDataBasic` and add a flag `hasAccess`). 
Again you fire a `LogoutEvent` and when you handle it you can do something like that:

```
TabDataDynamic tabData = (TabDataDynamic)getProxy().getTabData();
tabData.setHasAccess(false);
getProxy().changeTab(tabData);
```

In yout `TabPanel` implementation you have to make sure that the Tab is hidden, when the flag is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should take a look to GateKeeper which can be easily used with presenters like:

```
@ProxyCodeSplit
@NameToken(NameTokens....)
@UseGatekeeper( Your1GateKeeper.class)
public interface MyProxy extends TabContentProxyPlace<YourPresenter> {
}
```

And you can inject a Dashboard presenter to GateKeeper to check is this tab available:

```
@Singleton
public class Your1GateKeeper implements Gatekeeper{

 private DashboardPresenter presenter;

 @Inject
 public ReadOnlyGateKeeper(DashboardPresenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean canReveal() {
    return presenter.isAvailable();
 }

}
```

So using appropriate GateKeepers will allow you to reach required security.

Comment: I already have a Gatekeeper on my DashboardPresenter, but I did not think to have a Gatekeeper on my TabbedPresenter's, so I will definitely add that. Thank you, Kirill! But it does not solve my problem with unload/unbinding the presenters, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I suggest to move display logic from onBind to Gatekeeper. So you will not need to deal with unloading. Do not think that real unload is reachable, but you can easily not display some tabs.